# Why isn't my pointer correctly dereferencing to my desired output?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

Ok so here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void convert_weight(int x , char a,  int* y, char* b)
{
    if (a == 'F')
        *y = (x-32) * 5 / 9;
        *b = 'C';

    if(a == 'C')
        *y = x*9 / 5 + 32;
        *b = 'F';
}

int main() 
{

  int degrees1 = 50, degrees2;
  char scale1 = 'F', scale2;
  convert_weight(degrees1, scale1, &degrees2, &scale2);
  printf("%d %c = %d %c\n", degrees1, scale1, degrees2, scale2);
  degrees1 = 10;
  scale1 = 'C';
  convert_weight(degrees1, scale1, &degrees2, &scale2);
  printf("%d %c = %d %c\n", degrees1, scale1, degrees2, scale2);
  return 0;

}
```

And here is the output:

```
50 F = 10 F
10 C = 50 F
```

Notice that my first line is returning 10 F instead of 10 C.  I'm not quite sure why this is happening.  If `char a == 'F'` then I'm attempting to set scale2 to be equal to 'C' via derefrencing, much like I did for degrees2 where it seems to have worked perfectly.  I can't see the error in my code that's causing me to get 'F' for both of the outputs.

Comment: Previous Python programmer?  You need braces; not enough to just indent.

Comment: Ok ok!  I changed it to 'convert_temp()' for my final final version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing braces:

```
void convert_weight(int x , char a,  int* y, char* b)
{
    if (a == 'F')
    {
        *y = (x-32) * 5 / 9;
        *b = 'C';
    }

    if(a == 'C')
    {
        *y = x*9 / 5 + 32;
        *b = 'F';
    }
}
```

Without the braces, `*b` will always be `'F'`.

Comment: Oh man, that was it... I changed it to a simple if-else just now, I been attempting to learn pointers and such all morning, I guess in my haste I just forgot how to make decent code lol.  THANKS!

Comment: Indenting is a great aid in readability, but it can also mask logic errors.  Sometimes a second pair of eyes is what you need.

Comment: Also, why isn't it convert_temp() ?

Comment: @Jim lol.  I totally missed that.

Comment: Because the main() was given to me and I had to write the function that it calls, in this case it's weight.  I thought it was odd too but it's what my professor sent me... I could probably change it though :p

Comment: @DanielLoveJr if a get weird errors relating to blocks of code, I often run a quick format of the code to do the indentation for me.  If you do that with your original code, you will see that the first line under the `if` stays indented, while the second does not.  when the indentation mismatches what you think it should be, it indicates a problem with your blocks.

Comment: How do you run a format of the code?  I am curious.  I'm simply using TextWrangler and GCC within terminal.

Comment: @DanielLoveJr You'll need a beautify script.

Comment: Ah hrm, well that seems like something to investigate another day!  For now it's on to answering my next question.  Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot `{}` around your `if()` tests:

In the absence of any `{}`, only the **FIRST** line after the `if()` becomes the code to execute:

```
if (a == 'F')
    *y = (x-32) * 5 / 9;   // part of the IF
    *b = 'C';              // NOT part of the IF
```

So your `*b = 'F'` always executes, forcing you to report `F` always.

You want

```
if (a == 'F') {
    *y = (x-32) * 5 / 9;
    *b = 'C';
}
```

type code for both `if()` blocks.

Comment: Thanks to you as well!

Answer (score 1):

In first case you change passed variable two times. You need explicit exit from function after changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void convert_weight(int x , char a,  int* y, char* b)
{
    if (a == 'F') {
        *y = (x-32) * 5 / 9;
        *b = 'C';
        return;
    }

    if(a == 'C') {
        *y = x*9 / 5 + 32;
        *b = 'F';
        return;
    }
}

int main() 
{

  int degrees1 = 50, degrees2;
  char scale1 = 'F', scale2;
  convert_weight(degrees1, scale1, &degrees2, &scale2);
  printf("%d %c = %d %c\n", degrees1, scale1, degrees2, scale2);
  degrees1 = 10;
  scale1 = 'C';
  convert_weight(degrees1, scale1, &degrees2, &scale2);
  printf("%d %c = %d %c\n", degrees1, scale1, degrees2, scale2);
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: still needs braces around the second `if`.  will produce undesired results if anything should be executed after both `if`s.

Answer (score 1):

You need curly braces:

```
void convert_weight(int x , char a,  int* y, char* b)
{
    if (a == 'F') {
        *y = (x-32) * 5 / 9;
        *b = 'C';
    }
    if(a == 'C') {
        *y = x*9 / 5 + 32;
        *b = 'F';
    }
}
```

because else only the first statement is controlled by the `if`.

Comment: @glutton - No you don't

Comment: No, `void` functions don't need `return` statements.

Comment: @Gluttton no. you don't